# What is best method for SSR(server side rendering) debugging in Nuxt

Tags: node.js, debugging, vue.js

I created a web application dashboard with Nuxt and Nodejs. i have some difficulties from server side part.I searched web to discover how to SSR debugging ways in Nuxt but none of them worked.

for example: https://codeburst.io/debugging-nuxt-js-with-visual-studio-code-724920140b8f

I want to attach application to a debugger or any appropriate way for debug.
Any experience or suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: FWIW I went ahead and followed that guide and it worked fine. I didn't even have VSCode before..

Comment: Are you checked it on windows OS ?

Comment: I did not, that's true.

Comment: @FarhadAzarbarzinniaz did you find a solution? I tried from the same article and many other but couldn't debug server side